# where to call function for resizing UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have table where is changing content and i'd like to call method for changing height of this table.

from what method i can to call method for resising UITableView to set height to fit content??

thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to resize the `UITableView` because it is already a `UIScrollView`. You only need to add/subtract rows(content). For that, just reload the data as `[myTable reloadData];` and the table's size will be handled automatically. If you want to resize the `UITableView` then assuming that you already have a reference to it, just put the table in a new frame of your choice.